# Get posts under custom taxonomy and custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-post

I've created a page with list of custom terms:
[image]

Under each Term, i need to show every posts with post_type = 'courses'e taxnonomy = 'courses_category'

What will be the query to display those records?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use this code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'courses',
'tax_query' => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'courses_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'yourterm'
    )
),

    ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    // Show Posts ...
endwhile;
```

You can convert this in shortcode and just append it on your page trough your wordpress content editor or just insert this where you want to show your posts.

Check Codex or [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-taxonomies--cms-23090) link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'courses',
    'nopaging'=>true,
    'tax_query'=> array(
        array('taxonomy'=>'courses_category',
        'field'=>'slug',
        'terms'=>'recursos-humanos'//replace this with the term slugs
        )
    )
));
```

I would probably use three queries for the three terms you have above (changing the 'terms' value with the slug of the taxonomy term. You could get fancy and link all three terms together with a single query ordered by post type.

Comment: i've experiment this one but it returns nothing.....incredible,

Comment: @RuiCosta Strange. Make sure the tax_query is a nested array (array of an array) and double check the slug of the taxonomy term.

Comment: This is the nested array Array
(
    [post_type] => courses
    [nopaging] => 1
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => courses_category
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => recursos-humanos
                )
        )
)

Comment: @RuiCosta Did you register this taxonomy when you registered the custom post type? Refer to the `register_post_type()` function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/